# SharePoint Office 365 Create New Group in Page Tab

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to add a new group to the Page tab for SharePoint Office 365. I am using a SharePoint Add-in and adding a Custom Action for Ribbon. I am not sure what to put in the Elements.xml file to create the new group in the Ribbon for the Page Tab.

Comment: What's the type of this page ?

Comment: It's a PublishingPage. The site collection template is a Publishing PublishingPortal.